# Dynamicly Converting Type Object to Type (Some Class)

Tags: c#, object, types, casting, type-conversion

I would like some of my methods take an `Object` and convert it in to a useable type:

*Simple example

```
public void PostAction (object act){
    object Action = (act.GetType) act;
    string ActionName = Action.PostName;
}
```

From doing a little looking around the internet and Stackoverflow, I have found only ways to call an object's methods without a type

```
public void PostAction (object act){
    Type t = act.GetType(); // myObject.GetType() would also work
    MethodInfo GetPostName = t.GetMethod("GetPostName");
    GetPostName.Invoke(act, null);
}
```

Is there a better way? Can I cast a Object to its Type??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `dynamic`:

```
public void PostAction (object act){
    ((dynamic)act).GetPostName();
}
```

But I would go further and change the approach:

1. Declare interface with your `GetPostName` method:

   ```
   public interface IMyInterface
   {
       void GetPostName();
   }
   ```
2. Implement the interface in your class
3. Change `PostAction` method to take `IMyInterface` parameter:

   ```
   public void PostAction(IMyInterface act)
   ```
4. Use the interface method withing `PostAction` method:

   ```
   public void PostAction(IMyInterface act)
   {
       act.GetPostName();
   }
   ```

Benefits:

- would give you a compile-time type safety
- would be faster, because wouldn't require reflection

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I will try using the interface for some of my code....  I only see one issue : I have one method that the takes a object, (slice) and and replaces it's respective slice in the object  (whole)..... Would I need to cast it? Or can I return the object itself in an interface and cast that?? Or is there some other fancy way to do it :)

Comment: You can specify method return type as an interface. Actually, it's quite common practice.

Comment: Would you mind posting a demonstration of that!! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You should actually never use reflection to invoke a method of an object you pass in.
And it is also not really best practice to use object as parameter type of a method.
You usually want your code strongly typed.

Anyways, if you want "object" as the type of your parameter, simply cast the object to an interface or type:

```
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        string GetPostName();
    }

    public void PostAction(object actObject)
    {
        var action = actObject as IMyInterface;
        if (action != null)
        {
            var postName = action.GetPostName();
        }
    }
```

If you cast like this, the result can be null if the object does not implement that interface, thats why you might want to check against null...